# What does it mean to write two arrays together?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

```
const theme = createMuiTheme({
  spacing: factor => [0, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64][factor],
});

theme.spacing(2); // = 8
```

This is a sample code in the Material-UI framework document.
Here is the original link to the code：https://material-ui.com/customization/spacing/

Comment: The `[factor]` isn't an array, it's bracket notation which is accessing an element from the array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only have one array in your code block. If you've used arrays before you should be familiar with how you can access indexes within the array to get particular elements:

```js
//           0  1  2   2   3   4
const arr = [0, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64];
const eight = arr[2];
console.log(eight);
```

Above, I'm using [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors#Bracket_notation) (`[2]`) which allows you to access a given element within the array. We can rewrite the above code to use the literal array `[0, 4, 8, 16, 32, 41]` in place of the `arr` variable like so:

```js
const factor = 2; // make 2 a variable called `factor`
const eight = [0, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64][factor];
console.log(eight);
```

As you can see, `[factor]` is being used to get a particular value (using bracket notation) from the array `[0, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64]`.

Answer (score 1):

`[factor]` is not an array or a list, it's to get the element from the `[0, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64]` as an argument, like in this code

```
const theme = createMuiTheme({
  spacing: factor => [0, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64][factor],
});

theme.spacing(2); // = 8
```

The `spacing` is function and the `factor` is parameter / argument

Comment: What syntax is this, can you give me a link about this syntax

Comment: That's an [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions). Same as, `spacing: function(factor) { return [0, 4, 8, 16, 32, 61][factor]; },`.